# Как вырезать область в UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

Доброго вечера всем! Подскажите пожалуйста как можно вырезать область в UIView, чтобы эта область была прозрачной? Нашел, что можно как-то через маску, но всё же не понял как это сделать, не получается с реализацией.

Наложить слой с цветом фона не вариант, т.к. фон градиент.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте сабкласс `UIView` таким образом:

**Header (.h) file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TranparentView : UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
    backgroundColor:(UIColor*)color 
   transparentRects:(NSArray*)rects 
             circle:(BOOL)circle;
```

**Implementation (.m) file:**

```
#import "TranparentView.h"

@implementation TranparentView {
    NSArray *rectsArray;
    UIColor *backgroundColor;
    BOOL isCircle;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
    backgroundColor:(UIColor*)color 
   transparentRects:(NSArray*)rects 
             circle:(BOOL)circle {

    backgroundColor = color;
    rectsArray = rects;
    isCircle = circle;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.opaque = NO;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    for (NSValue *holeRectValue in rectsArray) {
        CGRect holeRect = [holeRectValue CGRectValue];
        CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );

        if (isCircle) {
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
            {
                CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                CGContextClip(context);
                CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
                CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
            }
        } else {
            [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
            UIRectFill(holeRectIntersection);
        }
    }
}
```

И в Вашем контроллере, например, создаете `TranparentView` с настройками:

`backgroundColor` - цвет вью;

`transparentRects` - массив рамок;

`circle`(BOOL) - yes - круг/овал, no - квадрат/прямоугольник.

так:

```
NSArray *transparentRects = @[[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 60, 50)]];

TransparentView *transparentView = [[TransparentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) backgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] transparentRects:transparentRects circle:NO];

[self.view addSubview:transparentView];
```

Вы можете вырезать как круглую область, так и квадратную. 
Код можно улучшить под Ваши нужды.
Надеюсь это Вам поможет.